# Can I make a scheduled auto-scaling policy in AWS to have 1 EC2 instance during specific hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks, aws-auto-scaling

I need to practice AWS for my job but I would like to reduce my personal costs as much as possible. I will only be working on my personal EC2 instance from noon to 11:00pm generally for the most part. Can I have an autoscaling group that will bring up the instance at noon and bring it down at 11:00pm? Saving me 13 hours of uptime a day, would this save on costs if it is possible?
I know about scheduled scaling options but I do not know if there is a configuration for 0 instances during down times. Desired 0? Minimum 0? Max 1? Unsure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [scheduled scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html) and define actions for start and stop at specific hours. For example:

Start:

Recurrence: 0 8 * * *

Desired capacity: 1

Stop:

Recurrence: 0 11 * * *

Desired capacity: 0

[image: Scheduled actions sample]

Comment: Ah! I was getting hung up on doing it all in 1 scheduled action, creating 2 makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Does the numbers for min max desired matter in the original policy or do the scheduled actions totally override them?

Comment: The scheduled action override any previous value for desired, min and max capacity. So the original policy could have a distinct value and it will be override when the sched action happens.